# Token Input refactored, now won't search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

```
  $('.token_input').each ->
    t = $(this)
    t.tokenInput t.data('url'),
      crossDomain: false
      prePopulate: t.data('load')
      preventDuplicates: true
      minChars: 4
      theme: 'facebook'
```

As you can see, I refactored the token_input so I could easiy add it to multiple fields if needed. It does work, it changes the field to a token field but when I am searching it's not doing anthing.

I have this script in coffee so I am not sure if I am missing something here. Thanks!

This is the original code (which works).

```
  $('#restaurant_cooking_style_id').tokenInput('/cooking_styles.json',
    { crossDomain: false, prePopulate: $('#restaurant_cooking_style_id').data('load'), preventDuplicates:true, theme: 'facebook', minChars: 4 }
    )


<%#= f.text_field :cooking_style_id, class: 'token_input', data: { url: '/cooking_styles.json'}, data: { load: @restaurant.cooking_styles.collect { |cooking_style| {:id => cooking_style.id, :name => cooking_style.style } } } %>
```

Comment: Do you have all the data attributes set up?

Comment: I believe I do, I updated my question with that.

Comment: The options for `f.text_field` are a Hash, you're trying to add two `:data` keys. Don't you want `'data-url' => '...', 'data-load' => '...'` or perhaps `:data => { :url => '...', :load => '...' }`? I'm assuming that you're really using `<%= f.text_field` rather than `<%#= f.text_field` too. When in doubt look at the HTML, that's what your CoffeeScript will be seeing.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about text_field is a hash. Did it the old way and it works fine! Thanks.